# C# System.ArgumentException: 'Parametre incorrect. Invalid subtype' in windows OCR

Tags: c#, ocr

In the Windows OCR avalaible here : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR

In OcrCapturedImage.xaml.cs, I can't figure out why in the line :

```
using (var currentFrame = await mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
```

I'm getting the following issue :

**System exception**

**System.ArgumentException: 'Parametre incorrect.**

**Invalid subtype'**

Here's the full method :

```
private async void ExtractButton_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Get information about the preview.
        var previewProperties = mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;
        int videoFrameWidth = (int)previewProperties.Width;
        int videoFrameHeight = (int)previewProperties.Height;

        // Create the video frame to request a SoftwareBitmap preview frame.
        var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, videoFrameWidth, videoFrameHeight);

        // Capture the preview frame.
        using (var currentFrame = await mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
        {
            // Collect the resulting frame.
            SoftwareBitmap bitmap = currentFrame.SoftwareBitmap;

            OcrEngine ocrEngine = OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(ocrLanguage);

            if (ocrEngine == null)
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser(ocrLanguage.DisplayName + " is not supported.", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);

                return;
            }

            var imgSource = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight);
            bitmap.CopyToBuffer(imgSource.PixelBuffer);
            PreviewImage.Source = imgSource;

            var ocrResult = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(bitmap);

        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: exception stacktrace!

Comment: Ok not sure what you meant, with ex.StackTrace here's what i get

Comment: at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) 
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
        at SDKTemplate.OcrCapturedImage.<ExtractButton_Tapped>d__17.MoveNext()